# Facebook like button not working

Tags: facebook

Facebook like button not working on my site.
It goes from like back to default as if it isn't passing some validation.

http://www.imageizer.com/

Once the problem is detected and solved, I'll edit the question to represent a minimal example that will benefit the SO community. Unfortunately I can't pull out the problem out yet as I'm not sure what it is..

Here is a screencast demonstrating the issue http://see.weareinto.com/8Hbq

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing it in?

Comment: Clearly you can see from the screencast that it wasn't - this is craziness!

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I assume you've changed some code since you posted this

Comment: I get this same behaviour on Google Chrome v 16.0.912.63 m on my site [http://www.cpi.poznan.pl/aktualnosci](http://www.cpi.poznan.pl/aktualnosci)
Everything seems to work on Firefox.

Comment: use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and make it PASS

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this is a problem happening on facebook's end.  But, there is a way you can fix it...  Just copy the URL of your page and enter it in the Facebook LINTER tool here:

Facebook LINTER -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I'm not sure of the exact details of why this works, but from what I've been able to gather, when you run the LINTER tool on your URL it will also update the cache facebook has for your URL. The error with the button working is on the facebook side, so by running this tool and getting facebook to update their cached data for your page, the like button starts working again. I've seen this broken facebook button occur for a few different reasons, one being that a page used to use the old facebook share button. When you add the new like button to a page that used to use a share button, the like button won't work until you run the page through the linter.

Bottom line is doing this will fix your like button. If your facebook button doesn't work on a page, run it through the LINTER tool. Hope this helps!

Comment: There was an intermittent issue with the Like Button for some of last week and over the weekend. We're pretty sure that we've got it fixed now, so this shouldn't happen again.

Comment: I upvoted the answer because of the helpful, astute answer. My first reaction was, "Downvote!" because Facebook should be downvoted on this.

Comment: Yes! This worked and I've been trying to figure this out for days! I will add one clarification to your answer - after entering the URL at the Facebook link provided above, the page on your website needs to be refreshed before it will work right and probably a refresh where you hold down CTRL while refreshing. Thank you!

Comment: What if your running your site locally? I've got social media buttons to work fine on local test instances of websites previously and now I am having a problem. Obviously the debugger won't be able to test a local instance, so how can I figure out if their caching is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Wordpress and you have the "Facebook Comments" plugin enabled, uncheck "Include OpenGraph Meta Information" at the very bottom of the Facebook Comments settings page. This was screwing it up for me.