# Facebook Like button not showing because URL is too long

Tags: html, facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm having incredible difficulty displaying the Facebook like button on my page, and after trial and error have concluded it's SOLELY because the URL of my facebook page is too long.

The code I'm entering is as follows:

```
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[name of my page]/[15
   random digits that FB assigned]" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-  
   width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

When I enter it correctly the LIKE button doesn't display on the website.  If I significantly shorten the URL to anything (even if it's not a real page), the like button displays!!

Really can't get my head round this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [custom username/page address](http://www.facebook.com/help/409473442437047/) for your facebook page. I'm not sure why you would be having a problem with the length of your URL (I'm doubtful that this is the real cause of the problem), but if that was the problem, this would fix it.

If that doesn't work, then perhaps running your page URL through [facebook linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will fix it like [this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698783/facebook-like-button-not-working#answer-6700317).

Comment: I'm a moron... it was because the Page hadn't been published! :P

Comment: Ha! Glad you found your answer :)